# Transferring values from popup page to parent page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a parent page inner4.aspx and a popup page popupemail.aspx . Now whats happening is I am extracting email ids in popup and displaying in the gridview and when the user selects an email id it gets tranferred through a javascript function to the parent page.

CODE FOR PARENT:

```
function setText1(txt) {
            document.getElementById('TextBox4').value = txt;
        }
```

CODE FOR POPUP:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        //TextBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;


        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "settxt", "setText1('"+ row.Cells[1].Text + "');", true);
    }
```

**The values are not getting transferred .** 
 Help please

Comment: can you just write a simple alert to see if the function is running also based on the way you set id make sure you have client side mode static

Answer (score 1):

Copy the modified line to your code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "settxt", "window.opener.setText1('"+ row.Cells[1].Text + "');", true);
```

Comment: it didn't work. should i remove the gridview from updatepanel??

Comment: can you trying by adding debugger; and run the project in debug mode (F5)         e.g. ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "settxt", "debugger;window.opener.setText1('"+ row.Cells[1].Text + "');", true);         and check if cursor stops at debugger; if it doesn not stop it means your whole script is not called

Answer (score 0):

you can call parent page by using javascript by using

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("TextBox4").value = txt;
```

or you can call parent page function by uisng same way

```
window.opener.setText();
```

setText() function written on parent page not in popup page.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise after the selected index changed set some property in the server side

```
in the cs
protected string SelectedValue{
   get {
      return "whatever";
   }
}


protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        //TextBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;


        SelectedValue = row.Cells[1].Text
    }

in the js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectedValue= '<%=SelectedValue%>';
    window.opener.document.getElementById("TextBox4").value = selectedValue;

});
```

there could be syntactical mistakes. Hope this helps.